# Best practice to call childclass method from parentclass object

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, casting

I know this question sounds confusing. Let me clarify myself.

```java
class Car ...

class Mercedes extends Car ...
class Porsche extends Car ... 




class Warehouse{
    Car car;
}


class WarehouseX extends Warehouse{
    public static void main(){
        ((Mercedes) super.car).doMercedesStuff();       
    }
}
```

Take a look at this fictional example. A Mercedes and a Porsche are a Car. Every Warehouse owns one car. 
Now, WarehouseX has a mercedes. However, WarehouseX inherits a generic car from Warehouse. 
What is the best way to call specific Mercedes methods on this car. One way would be to cast it to a Mercedes, but this seems ugly to me. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could give `Car` a method `doBrandSpecificStuff()`, override it in `Mercedes` and `Porsche` by just calling the real method there, like `@Override public void doBrandSpecificStuff() { doMercedesStuff(); }`. Kind of ugly, too, but I would like it more than casting instances... By the way, `Car` could be an `interface`, couldn't it?

Comment: Are you looking for a generic car container? Or what do you need to do with the warehouse?

Comment: Yeah this would work, but this would imply that you need a supermethod for every childmethod. And furthermore, how would one justify that if let's say a Mercedes has a method autocorrect() but a Porsche doesn't have this ability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since every warehouse should own only one specific car type, one could use generics:

```
class Warehouse<T extends Car>{

    T car;
}

class WarehouseX extends Warehouse<Mercedes>{
    //do mercedes stuff
}
```

WarehouseX can now access super.car and use it as Mercedes, since the inheritance 
garantees it.

Edit: And since people are talking about abstract methods: Car should one implement common methods and declare abstract method, if *each* specific car needs to provide them. If only a subset of specific car needs a method, like openBackDoors(), one should declare a new class extending Car.

Comment: Thanks to the generic WarehouseX does indeed know that it owns a Mercedes and therefore knows about Mercedes methods.

Comment: WarehouseX is a concretion of Warehouse<T..> and therefore not generic, but still, in WarehouseX, car is of type Mercedes. This is, because we say <T extends Car> so T must be a concrete class, which extends from Car and therfore adds more information

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That's not the point of generics tho. Of course after using that the car instance isn't a generic car anymore.

Comment: Yes, brain fart from me. I remove my comment. I was thinking of using generics like `Warehouse<Mercedes> w = new WarehouseX<>();`

Answer (score 3):

You should not create a dependency in that direction, a superclass can't know what the subclasses has implemented.

One solution is to create an abstract method in the super class

```
//Car class
public abstract void doModelSpecificStuff();
```

and then call it from somewhere in your Car class. Then each sub-class implements this method and does things specific for that car model

```
//Mercedes class
@Override
public void doModelSpecificStuff() {
    doMercedesStuff();
}
```

The Warehouse code would then be

```
class WarehouseX extends Warehouse{
    public static void main(){
        Warehouse warehouse = new WarehouseX();
        warehouse.car.doModelSpecificStuff(); 
    }      
}
```

To follow up on the answer by Legacy, if you make Warehouse generic you can then do

```
class WarehouseX extends Warehouse<Mercedes>{
    //...
    public void someMethod() {
        car.doModelSpecificStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: That code snippet mixing static/instance won't work and should be changed.

Comment: The code in the question was unclear, calling an instance from main without anything having been initialized so I took a shortcut and maybe it was to short :)

Answer (score 2):

You can give below code a try.
The idea is not to create multiple classes of Warehouse for each Car.
Make the code bit generic and use inject Car in warehouse at the time of creating the Warehouse object

```
abstract class Car{
    public abstract void doCarStuff();
}
class Mercedes extends Car{
    @Override
    public void doCarStuff() {
        System.out.println("Mercedes stuff");
    }
}
class Ferrari extends Car{
    @Override
    public void doCarStuff() {
        System.out.println("Ferrari stuff");
    }
}
class Warehouse{
    private Car car;
    public Warehouse(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }
    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }
}
public class TestCarWarehouse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Warehouse warehouseX = new Warehouse(new Mercedes());
        warehouseX.getCar().doCarStuff();
        Warehouse warehouseY = new Warehouse(new Ferrari());
        warehouseY.getCar().doCarStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing such a thing violates the Dependency Inversion principles.(For details see for SOLID principles).
Best practice is explained by Joakim. 
But you could try this:

instead of:

```
 Warehouse warehouse = new WarehouseX();
 warehouse.car.doModelSpecificStuff(); 

 try this:  
 getCar().doModelSpecificStuff(); 

//in Warehouse class 
//getters   //not pivate
//setters
```